# that after comma

Tags: commas, that

As far as I know, "that" cannot be used after comma, whether it functions as a relative pronoun or a conjunction. However, I've read this sentence from Hans Christian Anderson's fairy tale.

> So the bed of the sick girl was drawn nearer to the window, that she
>   might see the budding plant.

Considering the context, this line has nothing to do with "so-that" clause. Rather, this is relates to "so that(=in order that)" clause. Then my question is, how come that is used after comma?

Comment: Considering this text, *that* doesn't seem right.

Comment: This 'that' is an archaic variant of 'so that' (the introductory 'so' is a different issue). Whether or not the comma is acceptable is secondary to whether or not this usage is still acceptable. In context, it adds a nice period feel.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth *Archaic* is quite a strong term - in my view overused on the site. The first synonym which comes up when you google it is *obsolete*. I would just have said that the elision of *so* in *so that* is simply a bit old-fashioned.

Comment: @WS2 The first three relevant hits in a Google search for "that she might" -"so that she might" are a Bible verse, a Bible commentary, and, from 'Specimens of Bushmen Folklore', 'She first gently threw up wood ashes into the sky, that she might presently throw up huin roots'. I suggest you use a dictionary: [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/archaic) has: '1 : having the characteristics of the language of the past and surviving chiefly in specialized uses'.

Comment: Anderson's '…, that' seems fine, and reminiscent of almost any modern rendition of legend and that's just one example.

Who says 'that' can't follow a comma, please?